# WPF button gif animation

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm trying to achieve one Login button which changes to a Please wait... mode once pressed. I was thinking about some StoryBoard animation inside button or GIF image animation. Seems I'm pretty new to WPF and after several search attempts, I'm unable to find a fully working idea.

Login button idea
[image]

What would be the best way to do the above thing? Is there any way to eliminate the GIF image and create the same using some Path or something similar? Also note that I want this behavior of button to be triggered on Button.Click event.

Comment: You can do it easily without 3rd party libraries with one static image and `RotateTransform` story board. Activate on click but for how long?

Comment: Finally I did it using 3rd party GIF plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply add `WpfAnimatedGif` from your visual studio `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager->Package Manager Console.` There you find the Package adder window and type  `pm > Install-Package WpfAnimatedGif.` After a few seconds package should be added. Now firstly, you have add `namespace`  `xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"` then design your `Button.`

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow" Name="root"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
            Width="500" Height="500" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}">

        <StackPanel>
            <Button Name="BtnLogin" Width="100" Height="30" Content="Login" Background="Red" Margin="0,0,0,5" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button  Width="100" Height="30" Background="Red">
            <Grid>
                    <Image  gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding DataContext.LoadingImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Please Wait" Padding="30,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        </StackPanel>
       </Window>
```

The following .cs file is below and when you need to stop loading image, just assign `LoadingImage = null`;

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private ImageSource _LoadingImage;
        public ImageSource LoadingImage 
        {
            get { return _LoadingImage; }
            set 
            {
                _LoadingImage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LoadingImage");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadingImage = GetBitmapImage("/aaaa.gif");
        }
        public static BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(String location)
        {
            BitmapImage image = null;
            try
            {
                Uri iconUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/" + ";component" + location, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

                image = new BitmapImage(iconUri);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return image;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The above code will always show the gif. I want it only on Click event.

Comment: @Anup Could you indicate how did you solve it? I am interested in it. Please, share your solution. Thx.

Comment: @user1624552 As mentioned in the answer I followed the same step, i.e. WpfAnimateGif nuget package. Please note I didn't opt for change button text. Instead I displayed the animated gif along with a text in a separate control.